# How should operator plus implemented in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

I have a basic class, let's say `MyVector<T>`. I want the following expression to be as lazy (so as effective) as possible:

```
MyVector<int> x = a + b + c;
```

The semantichs of the `+` would be to concatenate the vectors, so `[1,2,3] + [2,3,4]` have to result in `[1,2,3,2,3,4]`. Let's say that I have `operator+=` and I can rely on that wherever needed. I think the following implementation is sufficient for the case when `a+b` gets evaluated:

```
template<typename T>
MyVector<T> operator+(MyVector<T> const &lhs, MyVector<T> const &rhs)
{
  return MyVector<T>(lhs)+=rhs;
}
```

Then I will have an rvalue (result of `a+b`) and an lvalue (`c`). So I suppose I have to write something like:

```
template<typename T>
MyVector<T> ??? operator+(MyVector<T> &&lhs, MyVector<T> const &rhs)
{
   ???;
}
```

What type should be returned here and how it has to be assembled?

Comment: Just my two cents: If I read `+` in the context of vectors, I'm thinking about linear combination, which is for example (for scalar values) `(1, 2, 3) + (4, 5, 6) = (5, 7, 9)` and I'd expect it to work for every type T that defines a `+` operator. I'd use `operator<< (MyVector<T>&, MyVector<T>&)` concatenation, so that would write `x = a << b`.

Comment: If you want to be lazy, you should look into expression templates. This allows you to accumulate all the concatenations and then perform them at once, which means you know the final size of the result vector.

Comment: @quantdev Wouldn't it result in an extra instance of `MyVector<T>`, even when the move construction and move assignment is correct?

Comment: @SebastianRedl I wouldn't think that this question could go that far. Let's think without them for now. :-)

Comment: @Notinlist Yes, you would get extra temporary `MyVector<T>` objects, but they would be move-constructed from rvalues, which *should* (assuming your move constructor is implemented sensibly) generally not be a noticeable problem. If it is, well then there's Jonathan Wakely's answer. :)

Comment: The first version will not move into the return value, because `operator+=` (probably) returns a lvalue reference, which is not eligible for copy elision. You would need to use `return std::move(MyVector<T>(lhs) += rhs);` to move it

Comment: @JonathanWakely Better: `MyVector<T> res(lhs); res += rhs; return res;` More readable, can use NRVO, and will still move if that fails.

Comment: @SebastianRedl, yep, that's what I showed in my answer, for the same reasons you give.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should definitely return an object, not a reference (otherwise concatenating rvalues can return a dangling reference).

If you want the concatenation to be optimal in all cases you would need to follow the example of `std::string` which provides four overloads for every combination of rvalue and lvalue:

```
X operator+(const X& l, const X& r) { X x(l); x += r; return x;}
X operator+(const X& l, X&& r) { r.insert(begin(), l.begin(), l.end()); return r; }
X operator+(X&& l, const X& r) { l += r; return l; }
X operator+(X&& l, X&& r) { l += r; return l; }
```

This will always reuse the existing memory in one of the arguments when (at least) one of them is an rvalue.

You should be careful about doing `return lhs += rhs;` because the result of `operator+=` is probably an lvalue reference, which won't be eligible for copy elision (RVO) or being moved into the return value. Either do `lhs += rhs; return lhs;` or `return std::move(lhs += rhs);` to ensure you don't force an unnecessary copy in the return statement.

You could optimise the last overload even further, by seeing which list is longer and appending to that one (e.g. if `l` is empty and `r` is very large `l += r` will copy every element when it could just return `r`)

```
X operator+(X&& l, X&& r)
{
  if (l.size() > r.size())
  {
    l += r;
    return l;
  }
  r.insert(begin(), l.begin(), l.end());
  return r;
}
```

Comment: I think we can better that with `std::move(r.begin(),r.end(),std::back_inserter(l)` and `std::move(l.begin(),l.end(),std::front_inserter(r))` if `T` is efficient for moving. Am I right?

Comment: It depends ... `back_insert_iterator` and `front_insert_iterator` add a single element at a time, which might cause additional reallocations and copying of elements (depending how you've implemented your container). The version in my answer _should_ allow the container to get the distance between the two iterators and resize before inserting anything (again, depending how you've implemented your container). If you have a `reserve()` member you could use that to pre-allocate before the `std::move()` algorithm, then it should be always better than the version in my answer.

Comment: But your type isn't going to be very simple with all these features ... I hope there's a good reason you can't just use `std::vector` !

Answer (score 2):

If your class is (fast enough) movable, you may give a single implementation which takes the first parameter by value:

```
template<typename T>
MyVector<T> operator+(MyVector<T> lhs, MyVector<T> const &rhs)
{
  return std::move(lhs += rhs);
}
```

A new `MyVector<T>` will be created for you transparently either by copying or by moving from the caller's parameter at the invocation point. The downside of this method is that copying/moving is done outside of the function call, that may make surprises with exceptions and debugging.

Comment: As written the compiler is required to copy the return value, it's not allowed to move it or elide it.

Comment: True, explicit `move` is needed there, fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to return a `MyVector<T>`. If your class has a move constructor or move-assignment operator then the compiler will call it, allowing you to more efficiently copy/assign the object.

As for the assembly, that will depend on the underlying implementation. `lhs += rhs` is a reasonable default, but you could also opt to do something like pass the parameters by reference and then allocate a result that pre-allocates a vector of length `lhs.size() + rhs.size()`.

Comment: OK. What about the assembly? Should I use `return lhs+=rhs;`, or something else?